# Can't connect to SFTP (with private key file) in Copy Data Tool

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from SFTP to blob but got stuck when creating SFTP source.

I have the connection details and can easily connect on Filezilla or WinSCP. However, I am unable to get it to work in Azure data factory.

I am not using code but the user interface.

The connection details on the page creating the SFTP source:
Connect via integration runtime: AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (default)

```
Host: xyz

Port: 22 (can't remove it as it doesn't like it)

SSH Host Key Validation: Enable SSH Host Key Validation

SSH Host Key Finger-print: taken from WinSCP - Session - Server/protocol information

Authentication type: SSH Public Key Authentication   -can't use basic as the private key holds the security info

User name:XXX

Private Key Type: Use Key Content

Private key content: loaded the .ppk file, tried also tried loading the .pem file and got different errors

Pass Phrase: none
```

When setting up this sftp in WinSCP or FileZilla it automatically converted the provided .pem file into .ppk.
When I loaded the .ppk file into ADF I got an error: Invalid Sftp credential provided for 'SshPublicKey' authentication type. 
When I loaded the .pem file I got: Meet network issue when connect to Sftp server 'spiderftp.firstgroup.com', SocketErrorCode: 'TimedOut'.

I have also tried 'Disable SSH Host Key Validation' in SSH Host Key Validation and made no difference.

I have also opened the .ppk file in PuttyGen and used that host key finger print and still no luck.

Only getting these 2 errors depending on which file I load.

Can't find anything about this online so would be grateful for some advice.

Answer (score 6):

Have you read this note in this doc?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp#using-ssh-public-key-authentication

SFTP connector supports RSA/DSA OpenSSH key. Make sure your key file content starts with "-----BEGIN [RSA/DSA] PRIVATE KEY-----". If the private key file is a ppk-format file, please use Putty tool to convert from .ppk to OpenSSH format.

Answer (score 6):

Got this working today. Like you, could connect using WinSCP and failed when using ADF.

The link Fang Liu shared contains our answers, but **my issue was not the private key**. I suspect Fang's suggestion resolved your problem and I'm sharing my answer here to help others who may encounter similar.

**My issue:**
When using Private Key Authentication in ADF the password becomes a **Pass Phrase** and you no longer have the ability to supply a password. **To overcome the problem we disabled password authentication** for the user and the SFTP connection started working.

As stated in the documentation. The **Pass Phrase** is used to **decrypt** the private **key if** it is **encrypted**.

**Also worth noting:**

1. If you store the contents of the private key in Key Vault you need
   to base64 encode the entire contents of the exported key and use
   that string. This includes "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" and the
   end. The same applies if you want to paste the value into the
   textbox of the SFTP linked service edit screen.
2. I did not try to manually edit the JSON of the Linked Service to explicitly provide a password and this could be workaround for someone to test if they are unable to disable the password.
3. I used PuTTYGen to export the PPK to a private key and had the same fingerprint issue too so I just disabled cert validation. Funnily you can use the fingerprint provided by the error and it passes validation so not sure where the bug lies. :-)

Comment: This seems to be talking aboutt my issue, but for point one in your 'Also worth noting' HOW do I base64 encode the key?  I am using powershell with the azure addin and it is adding the secrete buy I'm getting the error about base64 encoding when testing the linked service.

Comment: Have you tried:
$MYTEXT = 'This is my secret text'
$ENCODED = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($MYTEXT))
Write-Output $ENCODED

Comment: I ended up doing this...
$file = "C:\Development\blah.pem"
$content = (Get-Content $file -Raw)
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($content)
$encoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

Comment: @Nicholas Thanks a lot for point #1! ADF was mentioning directly that it's not base64 but you just simply made me aware of that! After converting to base64 it works also via Key Vault!